# Split a string at the carriage return in c#

Tags: c#

Im having a really hard time parsing a text file that I downloaded. it seems as though the the new line or carraige return is being included as part of the string. When I do

```
int i = 0;
While(i <= array.Length)
{
    Console.Write(array[i]);
    i++;
}
```

the returned data is printed to the console with a new line for some strange reason. Is there anyway to split the line at this carriage return?

Comment: Do want to just strip off the newline?

Comment: Do exactly as you say: `.Split("\n")`. Although it is rather unclear what you want to do precisely.

Comment: Not strange at all; `'\n'` and `'\r'` are perfectly ordinary characters.

Comment: Ive tried all of these and it says its not a valid character. The problem is that its shows up like this -> 1990-20-08\n130 i only want what comes afte rthe carriage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the file, the `'\n'` characters would be removed:

```
var array = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
```

This convenience method splits the file into separate lines, and stores the lines in an array.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Had to change up my code a bit but got it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string[] arrayOfStrings=yourString.Split("\n");
```

Comment: it returned an error saying I cannot convert an object expression to a string

Comment: Did it work? Otherwise give me some more details on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to remove the newlines from the end of the line strings, try this:

```
Console.Write(array[i].TrimEnd('\r','\n'));
```

Comment: Im really npot sure why this isnt working, it is still going straight to the next line without error. Im using Console.Write() not console.writeline()